# How to use Defined Name with Taget instead of Cell address?

Tags: excel, vba

The below code works fine if I used cell address with target , But when I used defined Name not works , **I tried `Target.name` and
I tried   `If Not Intersect(Target, [Test]) Is Nothing Then` but gives error**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        If Target.Address = "$H$1" Then     '[Test] is Cell H1 in current sheet
' I tried   If Not Intersect(Target, [Test]) Is Nothing Then
            Application.EnableEvents = True
             [Quarter_Select].value = Target.value 'That ,defined Name, works without problem
               End If               
End Sub
```

Comment: `intersect(names("test").RefersToRange,target)`

Comment: I got this error , "Application defined or object defined error"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the name is worksheet-scoped:

```vb
If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Names("TEST").RefersToRange) Is Nothing Then
```

If workbook-scoped:

```vb
If Not Intersect(Target, ThisWorkbook.Names("TEST").RefersToRange) Is Nothing Then
```

Comment: Works excellent